# Codename One - scanning barcodes checking for new line/ENTER character

Tags: android, codenameone, barcode

in Android I can easily detect the ENTER character using the setOnEditorActionListener method so that when a barcode is scanned into a textfield I know when the whole barcode has been read.

[Here is the Android code as requested:]

```
scanEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if ( (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN )))
            {
                System.out.println("   *** ENTER!");
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

I have been trying to replicate this in Codename One but with no luck. I have tried

- setDoneListener
- addDataChangedListener
- ActionEvent on the text field and text area
- overriding the keyPressed and keyReleased methods

but with no joy. If I set a textField with setSingleLineTextArea(false) I can see the barcode characters appear in the box followed by what I am assuming is a 
 new line character as the next scan appears on a new line. None of the methods listed seem to catch this event. If I change the focus to another box the ActionEvent is triggered but I don't want to have to move the focus each time.

[Here is the Codenameone code]

```
gui_searchTextField.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
gui_searchTextField.setDoneListener(new ActionListener()
{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
     {
        Dialog.show("KB", "doneListener " + 
        gui_searchTextField.getText().trim(), "OK", null);
     }
});
gui_searchTextField.addDataChangedListener((evt1, evt2) ->
{
  System.out.println("DataChanged " + gui_searchTextField.getText());
});
```

So, how do I catch the end of the barcode like I can easily in the Android SDK?

Comment: put some of your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text input is very much a special case for us in all OS's so the keys go directly into the native OS text editing and don't "travel" through Codename One API's. However, `DataChangeListener` should be invoked for every key input so I'm not sure how this is happening exactly.

I did notice you are using `System.out` instead of `Log.p` so you might miss the output from the device related to the changes. Also I would recommend overriding the key pressed/released events and not starting the text editing. Then adding the key value to the text field instead of letting the native input handle it e.g.:

```
class MyForm extends Form {
    public void keyReleased(int key) {
        if(isCrLf(key)) {
            // do this...
        } else {
            myTextField.setText(myTextField.getText() + ((char)key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. As an alternative way of scanning barcodes, is it possible to use a different scanner module when using the camera function? I have experimented with the cn1-codescan.cn1lib which I gather uses ZXIng. Is it possible to use another scanner module like Scandit?

Comment: We don't have builtin support for scannit but nick integrated support for zbar on Android in his QR scanner which is available in the extension manager too and you can check his source. Notice that on iOS we already use zbar and zxing is problematic on iOS. Integrating a QR scanner should be pretty easy as both of our libraries are available online and you can use them as a starting point for your own work